# ConverterNotFoundException on sending a string object to rest service in spring integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am trying to send a JSON string to a REST service from spring-integration through `http:outbound-gateway`.

But getting the error

> No converter found capable of converting from type java.lang.String to type org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?>

Sharing the relevant details

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway id="xtifygateway"
        request-channel="requestchannel" request-factory="requestFactory" 
        url="${xtifyUrl}" http-method="POST">
</int-http:outbound-gateway>

<int:header-enricher input-channel="requestchannel">
    <int:header name="Content-Type" value="application/json"/>
</int:header-enricher>
```

The Interface used for sending the request is

```
public interface RequestGateway
{
    ResponseEntity<?> pushNotification(String xtifyRequest);
}
```

I am using this code in java and calling the interface method.

```
  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
  try { 
      String xtifyJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(xtifyRequest); 
  }
```

Can anyone please help on this? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this one:

```
     <xsd:attribute name="expected-response-type" type="xsd:string">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                The expected type to which the response body should be converted.
                Default is 'org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity'.
                This attribute cannot be provided if expected-response-type-expression has a value
            </xsd:documentation>
            <xsd:appinfo>
                <tool:annotation kind="direct">
                    <tool:expected-type type="java.lang.Class" />
                </tool:annotation>
            </xsd:appinfo>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
```

From one side the `String` should be enough, but from other consider to use some your domain object. The `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` will its work for your on the matter.

Comment: ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            try
            {
              String  xtifyJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(xtifyRequest);
            }  I am using this code in java and calling the interface method.So should i remove this and use MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter ?

Comment: No, that's fine. You just need to specify `expected-response-type` as a `java.lang.String`.